What makes electric and magnetic fields in Yang-Mills theories gauge co-variant?
Specifically in QCD, why is it so?

In YM theory, the field strength $G$ is not invariant under gauge transformations. Indeed, under the gauge transformation
$$
A_{\mu} \to \Omega(x) A_{\mu} \Omega^{-1}(x) + i \Omega(x) \partial_{\mu} \Omega^{-1}(x), \tag{2.11}
$$
$G$ transforms as
$$
G_{\mu\nu}\to \Omega(x) G_{\mu\nu} \Omega^{-1}(x). \tag{2.12}
$$
Thus, the constructions
$$
E_i = G_{0i},\quad B_i = \dfrac{1}{2} \epsilon_{ijk} F^{ij},
$$
are not gauge invariant, as they transform accordingly to (2.12). See these notes by David Tong for more on this.
Note: I used $G$ instead of $F$ to indicate that it's the gluonic field, but the same is valid for any other $SU(N)$ theory.

Thanks a lot for those notes!
